# Using JQuery on changing sibling input of the same div group only

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I've been working on a code that would try to pre-fill some disabled inputs with a keyup() function from another enabled input that are all enclosed in one div element. What happens is that upon key release, it tries to change the value of the disabled inputs from that specific row of divs. Here's what I currently have on my code

```
    <div class="container-fluid" id="clonegrp">
        <div class="row grpit">
        <div class="col-md-7">
          <input type="text" name="it[]" class="form-control" id="item" placeholder="Chemical/Equipment*" required="true">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
          <input type="text" name="amount[]" class="form-control" placeholder="Amount*" required="true">
        </div>
        /<div class="col-md-1">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="max" placeholder="Max" readonly="readonly">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="unit" placeholder="Unit" readonly="readonly">
        </div>
      </div>
```

so this group of inputs can be cloned by some button and through this JQuery code

```
    var $button2=$('#add-item'),
    $row2=$('.grpit').clone(),
    $try2=$('#clonegrp');
    $button2.click(function() {
       $row2.clone().appendTo($try2);
    });
```

the problem lies at the part where I try to do the live keyup function

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#clonegrp').on('keyup','#item', function() {
            $('#max').val('some text');
        });
    });
```

I know that this is wrong since the id part would mess up which of the cloned inputs with the #max id gets to change the input. I can't seem to figure out how to get the #max sibling of the currently focused #item input. How do I do that?

Comment: use classes if you are cloning them - ids should be unique

Comment: All your related elements belong to a `.grpit`.  If you change them from ids to classes then it's a simple `$(this).closest('.grpit').find(otherChildClassSelector).val(newValue)`

Comment: @Taplar Thank you! This is exactly what I'm looking for.